# Installing template plugin

Tags: codeigniter

I need some help installing the template plugin for CI. Ive dowloaded and copyied the files and folders to the right places but a simple

```
function index()
    {        
        $this->template->render();      

    }
```

in my Welcome (fresh install of CI) results in a error and im thinking im suppose to include the template plugin in the config/autoload somewhere?

Ive tried to follow http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/start.html but it does not describe how to intergate the plugin with the system (unless i missed something)

(the error is "Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in")

Comment: Have you loaded the class? You will need to do this before you can run the command.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to $autoload['libraries'] in application/config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('template');
```